# Nginx sites-available doesn't work

Tags: nginx

I've got this really simple *server* block under *sites-available*.

**Problem**: When I try to access to *mydomain.com*, Nginx returns a « 404 Not Found », but if I try to access to a file in particular, it works fine, like *mydomain.com/index.php*

```
server {

    listen          80;
    index           index.php;
    server_name     mydomain.com;
    root            /home/myusername/sites/mydomain.com/htdocs;

    access_log      /home/myusername/sites/mydomain.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log       /home/myusername/sites/mydomain.com/logs/error.log;

    location / {
            try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Note that:

- my *hosts* file is configured ;
- I restart Nginx after each edit ;
- the access rights, user and group are correct ;
- the *error.log* file is empty, the *access.log* returns me all the 404 ;
- I tried to change the config by adding/removing some lines, still no changes ;
- the site is enabled in *sites-enabled* with a correct symlink (I tried to edit it and it opened the right file) ;
- I've got a few sites on the same server who runs well (so the including of *sites-available* and *sites-enabled* is OK, and Nginx works fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `try_files` directive is too restrictive and, I guess, is in wrong place.

Either remove `location /` completely, it doesn't makes much sense, or, at least add `$uri/` so `index` directive will work.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

But my guess is, you need to move this `try_files` into `location ~ \.php$`, this will make sure that php-file exsists before pass it to PHP-FPM for processing. All other files will be served by nginx with proper use of `index` directive.

```
server {
    listen          80;
    index           index.php;
    server_name     mydomain.com;
    root            /home/myusername/sites/mydomain.com/htdocs;

    access_log      /home/myusername/sites/mydomain.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log       /home/myusername/sites/mydomain.com/logs/error.log;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }    
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. it was just under my eyes!
i tried both solutions (being more precise within `location /` block and remove the block completely by moving down the `try_files` rule), and both worked.